# Javascript library for syntax-highlighting syslog text logs?

Tags: javascript, syntax, highlighting, syslog

I'm display some plain-text syslog output on a web page.  I'd really like to pretty-print it, highlighting dates and hostnames.  Are there any javascript syntax highlighting libraries which come with syslog support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice [JavaScript syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter). It doesn't support the syslog but since it is not a very complex format it shouldn't be too hard to create a [custom brush](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Brushes:Custom) for it.